# Confused on determining equilibria of a differential equation

Tags: calculus

So my final for calculus III is coming up, and I'm running through all the material from the past quarter. I am confused on one thing, though I'm sure it'll click as soon as someone helps me out, it's late and I'm confusing myself.

Question is: To find all equilibria as a function of the constant $a$

The given diffeq is $ x' = ax-x^2$

first of all, I'm assuming that the independent variable is time, right? $x' = dx/dt$?

Regardless, here's where I am:

$x' = g(x) = ax-x^2$

equilibria @ $g(x) = ax-x^2 = 0$

So when it says to "determine all equilibria as a function of the constant $a$", does this just mean that my answer can be: "Equillibria @ $a$ when $a=x$"?

Then, I can make a plot of $g(x)$ vs $x$, the curve of that plot will start at $(0,0)$, climb to a maximum, turn around, then hit $g(x) = 0$ at $(a, 0)$. And this is my Phase Plane, correct?

So by the stability criterion, this is a stable equilibrium, because $g'(x) < 0$.

So, a phase plane is a plot in which the x-intercepts tell me the equilibria points, and the derivative of $g(x)$ tells me the stability of each equilibia. Then what is the other plot called that shows families of solutions and identifies equilibria by horizontal asymptotes? In the case of the problem presented here, would I make one of those? By plotting $a$ vs $t$?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are 3 cases: $a<0$, $a=0$ and $a>0$.

You have to decide the stable point in each of the case and then describe the appearance of the solutions for different initial conditions....

I think that is what you are asked to do.